# Get resource group name from resource object Azure SDK Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

Just wondering if there is a simple way to get the resource group name from an Azure resource object i.e. Disk, Snapshot object

Currently I use the resource URI and derive the resource group from that:

```py
# ID example: '/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/MyRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/disk-a
resource_group = [value for value in str(disk.id).split("/") if value][3]
```

Output

```
>> MyRG
```

I can't seem to see a way to do something like:

```
disk.resource_group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_30.models.disk?view=azure-python), I don't believe there is a `resource_group` property.

What I usually do is create a method(similar to what you have done) to fetch the resource group from a resource ID:

```py
def get_resource_group_from_id(resource_id):
    return resource_id.lstrip("/").split("/")[3]
```

Then I just use this method everywhere I need to get the resource group:

```py
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile

compute_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)

for disk in compute_client.disks.list():
    resource_group = get_resource_group_from_id(resource_id=disk.id)
```

However, I'm not a fan of this since I'm used to just fetching this directly from the resource.

You could raise a **Feature Request** with [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues) to get this property included in the objects. Azure PowerShell and Azure CLI include this property, so I don't see why Azure Python SDK shouldn't include it.

Another option could be to include a `resource_group` tag, then you can fetch it directly from the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Azure SDK for python:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-python

I think your needs need to be specific to a specific service, And in general, a large range can be specific to a small range, but the specific objects of each service do not seem to define a method to obtain the corresponding resource group. I think your idea may not be realized.